# Laravel 5 Facebook Signed request function to get page id

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I have a page tab application where I get the page id from a signed request. To  get the page i call this function.

```
$facebook_page_id = get_Fb_Page_Id();
```

The problem is that this only works the first time I call the function. Why is this?

En exmaple would be that I have a startpage which returns some results but also a page that returns search results. The function only works on the startpage but not when returning search results.

Here is my function.

```
function get_Fb_Page_Id()
{

    $fb = App::make('SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk');
    $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

    try {
        $token = $fb->getCanvasHelper()->getAccessToken();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// Failed to obtain access token
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }

// $token will be null if the user hasn't authenticated your app yet
    if (!$token) {
// . . .
    }

    $id = $helper->getPageId();

    return $id;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the first page load returns the `signed_request` from Facebook (as Facebook sends this as `POST` to your app on first load). All subsequent page requests (i.e. submitting a form, or navigating to a different page) within your application will lost the `signed_request`.

To deal with this situation, you should add the `signed_request` data to `Session` on initial load, and then reference this later in your code.

For Example, on first load (and only when `signed_requests` exists), add Page ID to session:

```
Session::put('page_id', $helper->getPageId() );
```

Then, in subsequent code, and on other pages, just use the Session data:

```
$page_id = Session::get('page_id');
```